# Counteract X's -nocursor argument in a running server

Tags: xorg, cursor

I'm starting X on our media centre with the -nocursor argument. The cursor is still there, it's just invisible, which is what I want 99.9% of the time.

However recently there have been times where having a cursor might be advantageous however I don't want to restart X (or spawn another instance) just to have a cursor.

Is there a way of toggling the cursor visibility in X? Something I can either bind in or enter in over SSH (which is acceptable in my use-case).

Comment: hello, did you manage to get that configuration? I am interested, too

Comment: @scjorge Unfortunately not